# comparing multidimensional arrays with sizeof()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array made up of arbitrary length arrays.

```
int foo[] = {99, 1, 2};
int baz[] = {9, 8};
int tar[] = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6};

int *stuff[] = {foo, baz, tar}
```

I do not know the size of any of these arrays, I need to discover the size using `sizeof()` but I am getting strange results that do not seem to make sense when I compare them.

For example when I print the memory locations they are the same:

```
printf ("%p ", foo);
printf ("%p ", stuff[0]);

> 0x7ffef86f8de4 0x7ffef86f8de4
```

And when I print the first values of the array they are the same:

```
printf ("%d ", foo[0]);
printf ("%d ", stuff[0][0]); 

> 99 99
```

**However, here is the problem, when compare them with `sizeof()` they are NOT the same:**

```
printf ("%lu ", sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]));
printf ("%lu ", sizeof(stuff[0])/sizeof(stuff[0][0]));

> 3 2
```

Comment: The type of `foo` is _array_.  The type of `stuff[0]` is _pointer_.  The `sizeof` operator is calculated at compile-time.  You cannot use it to infer the size of an array type from a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you *don't* have an array of arrays, you have an array of *pointers*.  So `sizeof(stuff[0])` gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array that pointer points at.  Once you convert an array to a pointer (which happens pretty much any time you use the array, since you can't really do much of anything with arrays themselves), the size of the array is lost.

Comment: Can you explain the numbers in the output? I tried but did not see through this (only the first one is clear to me). Is it UB?

Comment: @Yunnosch - the output is all defined. E.g. `sizeof(stuff[0])/sizeof(stuff[0][0])` is simply `sizeof (a pointer) / sizeof (int)` and from the answer of `2` it is apparent it is on a 64-bit box.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The output is not all defined. Using the conversion specifier `%p` with a type not compatible with `void *` is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Well, yes, you do need to add `(void*)` to print the pointers `:)`